# Android FTP file transfer (explicite TLS) failed and create a empty file

Tags: android, ftp

I try to upload some files to a ftp server with explicite TLS.

My code work until the it upload the files. It throws an IOException.

The last response from the server (getReplyStrings()) is

> [150 Accepted data connection]

In the upload folder it generates a empty file. I have no access to the FTP log on the server.

```
FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient("TLS",false);
ftp.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = null;
try {
    kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(null, null);
    KeyManager km = kmf.getKeyManagers()[0];
    ftp.setKeyManager(km);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (KeyStoreException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

ftp.setBufferSize(1024 * 1024);
ftp.setConnectTimeout(100000);

try {
    ftp.connect("domain.com");
    ftp.setSoTimeout(1000000);
    if (ftp.login("login", "passsword")) {
        ftp.execPBSZ(0);
        ftp.execPROT("P");
        ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/");
        if (ftp.getReplyString().contains("250")) {
            ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            BufferedInputStream buffIn;
            for(File file : files) {
                Log.d("DEBUG","Uploading: " + file.getPath());
                buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                boolean result = ftp.storeFile(file.getName(), buffIn);
                buffIn.close();
            }
        }
        ftp.logout();
    }
    ftp.disconnect();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ftp.getReplyStrings()));
    System.out.println(e);
    Log.d("DEBUG", Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
}
```

This are the last lines from logcat:

```
09-14 19:54:01.821 18538-18571/com.google.observer 
D/DEBUG: Uploading: /storage/emulated/0/temp/1_20160709_162505.jpg.jpg
09-14 19:54:02.871 18538-18571/com.google.observer 
I/System.out: [150 Accepted data connection]
09-14 19:54:02.871 18538-18571/com.google.observer 
I/System.out: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x7f9d8c6200: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
09-14 19:54:02.881 18538-18571/com.google.observer 
D/DEBUG: 
[com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method),
com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:877),
java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:185),
java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:85), 
java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:61), 
java.io.BufferedOutputStream.close(BufferedOutputStream.java:152), 
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._storeFile(FTPClient.java:666), 
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:624), 
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:1976), 
com.google.observer.Ftp.upload(Ftp.java:66), 
com.google.observer.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:30)]
```

Comment: You catch a lot of exceptions.Good. But you continue with the code as if nothing happened. You should at least put a return statement in every catch block.

Comment: What do you mean with return statement? The lines from the logcat are from the __for__ lopp, where I upload the files. before there are no errors. In the Logcat you see the the Log.d("DEBUG","Uploading: " + file.getPath()); and than comes the IOException.